# Updating a React prop with setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use React for the first time and am looking for a way to push the contents of an array that updates with new data every 4 seconds into a H3 tag. I know that this could be achieved with vanilla JS but want to know if there is a nice, clean way to do this through the React ecosystem.

At the moment the function runs and the console log shows that the array is being updated at precise intervals, however, the actual H3 tag stays empty.

I've tried to utilise componentHasMounted() and tried to look at ways to put the render() function inside of the professions() function but couldn't figure out a way to properly encapsulate it (if that is even possible). I've also tried to follow the new Date() tutorial for updating rendered elements in the React docs but to no avail - I'm sure it's likely to be a mistake at my end but any help from the SO community would rock.

Heads up, I'm using create-react-app for this.

Here's the code:

Profession.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Profession.css';

class Profession extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {profession: professions()};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Profession">
          <div className="keyboard">
          <h3>{this.state.profession}</h3>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function professions() {
    const professionList = ['Developer', 'Designer'];
    var profession = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < professionList.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(function (i) {
            return function () {
                profession = [];
                profession.push(professionList[i]);
                console.log(profession);
                return profession;
            }
        }(i), 3800*i);
    }
}




export default Profession;
```

And App.js just in case

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Profession from './Profession'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">


        <h1>Sunil<br/>Sandhu</h1>
        <Profession />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the local state `profession` inside `professions()` and not in `constructor`. Also, `professions()` should be a part of the component so that it can update local state. This will trigger the component to update and update `H3`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Profession.css';

class Profession extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // set 'profession' default to null
    this.state = {profession: null};

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // call professions() here
    this.professions();
  }

  professions() {
    const professionList = [
      'Sunny',
      'Developer',
      'Designer',
      'Programmer',
      'Notebook Hoarder',
      'Developer',
    ];

    for (let i = 0, l = professionList.length; i < l; i++) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        // update local state property 'profession'
        that.setState({ profession: professionList[i] });
      }, 4000*i);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Profession">
        <div className="keyboard">
          <h3>{this.state.profession}</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Profession;
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hey thanks for the input Rahul, appreciate it. I'm essentially just trying to get the h3 to output the first item in the array, rather than the entire array. But now that you mention it, it actually makes much more sense to just set the profession variable to the value of professionList[i]. Just going to give that a shot now and will report back to see if your code has worked. :)

Comment: Hmmm, I've used your exact code but the H3 tag is still being rendered as empty. It's also now returning a this.setState is not a function. If I remove the line this.setState({ profession }), the page loads and the function appears to now be running inside of the class, but the H3 tag still remains empty :(

Comment: Ah I think I see what the issue was with the code -  this.setState was definitely required, but it was trying to reference 'this' with respect to the setTimeout() function, rather than the component prop. 

So now the page is rendering with the updated content - so many thanks! I'll make an edit to your answer and then mark as correct :)

Comment: @SunilSandhu, good catch! Also I believe it would be more appropriate to invoke `this.professions()` in `componentDidMount()` instead of `render()`.

Comment: You are completely right about that! I've edited the answer again to now include that too. :)

Comment: @SunilSandhu I have optimized your code a bit further. FYI - you dont have to handle `this` separately if you use ES6 arrow functions `=>`

Comment: Ah that's great! I did try to use arrow functions for that very reason but I had a bit of difficulty getting it to work at the time but it looks like that may have been because other parts weren't working at the time. Thanks so much for your help with this - feel free to check out www.sunilsandhu.com if you are at all interested in seeing what I needed the code for :)